# RecyclerView adapter doesn't update on notifyDataSetChanged() (not Collection)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

It's a first time I run into this when it's not about ArrayList, List, or any sort of collections - it's about Int.

I'm using Kotlin and Moxy's Presenter to initialize adapter. 
Here's how I init this :

```
adapter = WeeksAdapter(context, weeks, chosenWeekPosition, this)
```

here's my WeeksAdapter part :

```
    class WeeksAdapter (private val context: Context, private val weeks: ArrayList<WeekChoice>, var chosenPosition: Int, private val listener: OnCurrentWeekChangedListener):
        RecyclerView.Adapter<WeeksAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            val week = weeks[position]
            holder.tv.background = context.resources.getDrawable(
                if (position == chosenPosition) R.drawable.week_circle_background_active else  R.drawable.week_circle_background_inactive , null)
            holder.tv.setTextColor( context.resources.getColor ( if (position == chosenPosition) android.R.color.white else  R.color.textColor ))
            holder.tv.text = "${week.numberOfWeek}"
            holder.tv.setOnClickListener {
                listener.onWeekClick(position)
            }
        }
}
```

so, when I change chosenPosition field in my Presenter and call `adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()` - chosenPosition doesn't change or update in adapter - I checked it in debug - it doesn't change.

How can I fix it, please

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this presenter, but your chosenPosition doesn't not change. It doesn't change after you have created your adapter. You need function for update it

```
class WeeksAdapter (private val context: Context, private val weeks: ArrayList<WeekChoice>, var chosenPosition: Int, private val listener: OnCurrentWeekChangedListener):
        RecyclerView.Adapter<WeeksAdapter.ViewHolder>() {


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val week = weeks[position]
        holder.tv.background = context.resources.getDrawable(
                if (position == chosenPosition) R.drawable.week_circle_background_active else  R.drawable.week_circle_background_inactive , null)
        holder.tv.setTextColor( context.resources.getColor ( if (position == chosenPosition) android.R.color.white else  R.color.textColor ))
        holder.tv.text = "${week.numberOfWeek}"
        holder.tv.setOnClickListener {
            listener.onWeekClick(position)
        }
    }

    fun updatePosition(newPosition: Int) {
        chosenPosition = newPosition
    }
}
```

update position through this function, and then invoke adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: I don't change them. I change the chosenPosition

Comment: Ok. The same problem. It doesn't change

Answer (score 0):

Do the call to notifyDataSetChanged() from the UI thread.

Comment: how do I do it if it's not from activity?